# Flutter: making column scrollable via SingleChildScrollView truncates the column

Tags: flutter

I have a sign-up page that consists of a column, text fields, and sign-up buttons. The code looks something like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Align(...)
            Form(...),
            socialLoginSeparator(context),
            socialLoginButtons(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Focusing on any of the `TextFormFields` in the `Form` opens the keyboard, which causes the column to overflow at the bottom and I get the following error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.7 pixels on the bottom.
```

I have been trying to fix this and understand that it is possible to address this by wrapping the `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView`. Doing so resolves the overflow error but it appears to truncate the column at the bottom... i.e., when I dismiss the keyboard (causing the column to automatically scroll to its 'natural' position) and try to drag+scroll the column again, it gets truncated in the middle of the screen. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the full Information, This can be the solution,
If this doesn't work please comment here,

```
Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(...),
        backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
        body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Align(...)
                  Form(...),
                  socialLoginSeparator(context),
                  socialLoginButtons(context),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
```

Comment: Thanks @yousuf... using `Expanded` was causing some issues so I skipped that and went with `SizedBox` -- > `SingleChildScrollView` --> `Column`. This **almost** works... I don't get overflow or truncation now but the problem is that the column remains scrollable **after** the keyboard is dismissed. I would like to keep it unscrollable after keyboard dismissal (i.e., same behavior as before the keyboard is opened)... is this possible?

Comment: Yeah If you want to make screen unscrollable you can you physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), this. "physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() inside SingleChildScrollView.